# Python cannot find module in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have some Python code that imports a module named "datasets"
I work in VSCode on Winows 10
I created a virtual environment with Python 3.11.4 64bit
In the VScode terminal I install all modules with PIP->VScode does not report any errors.

When I run the code I get the error:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\Hubert\Desktop\courses\PyTorch\Transformer-from-scratch\train.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Hubert\Desktop\courses\PyTorch\Transformer-from-scratch\train.py", line 10, in <module>
    from datasets import load_dataset
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datasets'
```

I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

Who can help?

Comment: You must make sure to install **into the virtual environment that VSCode is using**, by using **its Python executable** to run Pip. Please see the linked duplicate for details. I don't use VSCode, but it most likely has its own UI for doing this. If the package is properly installed in the correct virtual environment, you will need to double-check what package you are installing and what name should be `import`ed in the code - **these do not necessarily match**, and you must **read the documentation** for the package to make sure.

Answer (score -1):

judging by the error, you have not downloaded the datasets library in the virtual environment
You can fix it like this

```
pip install datasets
```

Comment: Tried that already. Install went  correct. But I still get the error